# Is it possible to have active low window comparator using open collector output opamps?

Tags: operational-amplifier

My textbook uses opamps with active pullup and  diodes:
\$A1\$ drives the load when \$v_{in}\lt LTP\$
\$A2\$ drives the load  when \$v_{in}\gt UTP\$
None drives the load when \$LTP\lt v_{in} \lt UTP\$

There is a serious limitation with this as ***it cannot drive loads with different supply like TTL***.
So I'm wondering ***if this can be done using open collector opamps***. Any help?

Btw I know how to work the active high output window comparator using open collector opamps. It is the active low output as shown in the diagram I'm not able to get..

[image]

Comment: You could use open collector *comparators*.

Comment: I want to use basic open collector *opamps*.  This is fixed. Logically it seems I need to make OR gate using open collector inputs. Looks it is impossible? Because open collector can only ground the node, so only AND gate is possible with pullup resistor?

Comment: There is little difference between an opamp and a comparator (a comparator is not internally compensated) and I am not aware of any open collector / drain opamps; why make your life more difficult than needed?

Comment: @PeterSmith actually I don't want to make anything haha! I'm only wondering if it were *impossible* to get active low output

Comment: @PeterSmith something like this https://prnt.sc/rqujpc

Comment: My textbook uses `open collector opamps for active high`, but it switches to `active pull up opamps for active low`. So it made me wonder if it were impossible to `use open collector opamps and get active low`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open collector opamps don't exist as an opamp needs to have an output that can be driven low or high.
- Open collector **comparators** do exist, the [LM393](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm393-n.pdf) is a popular example.

As mentioned in the comments, with open collectors outputs and diodes you can only make an **OR** function. We can still use something similar as can be seen in the schematic that I made:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGDhqA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that I have drawn the open collector comparator explicitly as a comparator with an NPN. That is similar to what is inside for example the LM393. So Comp1 and Q1 would be on the same chip.

Now the output signal will be **high** when Vin is within the window.

Just add an inverter and you will get a signal that is **low** when Vin is inside the window.

Comment: Clever! But why do we need those `diodes` ? Can't we just short the bjts' outputs and hook directly to the pullup resistor? Your circuit is functionally equivalent to this https://prnt.sc/rqujpc right?

Comment: *Can't we just short the bjts' outputs and hook directly to the pullup resistor?* Indeed we can. The diodes aren't needed. I left them in to make the circuit look more similar to the one from your question.

Comment: I see thank you so much:) By inverter hopefully you mean a pulldown npn with a pullup resistor...

Comment: *By inverter hopefully you mean a pulldown npn with a pullup resistor.* Yes or an inverter that is inside an IC for example the 7404, it has 6 inverters.